# Can amazon lambda post to sqlite database of a django app hosted on EC2?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sqlite, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda script that produces a json file, 
and a django app on an AWS EC2 instance.

I want to make the json available to the django app.

The django app has a default sqlite3 db, how can I get lambda to post to EC2?

I am using the code below to post the results to a AWS RDS instance, but this might be costly for my needs and I'd be better off updating a db in the django app, of possible.

```
######################
# Save to RDS database
######################
try:
    created_at = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO entries (created_at, useremail, datajson) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
                    (created_at, user, datastr))
        conn.commit()
    # logging.info("Added to RDS MySQL table")
except:
    print('Could not save to RDS')
    # logging.info("Could not save to RDS")
```

(The lambda script is in python2)

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database. I don't think you can access it remotely. It sounds like you need to stick with RDS, or at least run MySQL on the EC2 server.

Comment: Thanks. I migrated the db to a MySQL one in the django application. Do you think it is possible to have lambda POST to a MySQL hosted on a EC2? Any docs/tutorial to look at? Thanks

Comment: Open the port on the EC2 security group, and run the Lambda function in the VPC.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html for a little more reference on getting a lambda into a vpc. You just need to get your lambda on the same subnet as your ec2 with the db (unless you need OS level access to your db server I would recommend RDS, same deal making lambda talk to it)